# Speeding up webcam access in Java OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv, video

I am porting part of my C++ OpenCV-based code to Java OpenCV. I am using the Java wrappers prepared by Willow Garage, i.e., the group behind c++ OpenCV. I am not using javacv (hosted at googlecode).

Part of this code accesses the video stream of the webcam and processes it. With C++ I am able to show the webcam video in 'real-time': if I wave my hand, the video on the screen shows me waving a hand. With Java if I wave my hand the video (taken from the webcam) is not able to keep my pace: the frame rate is incredibly slow.

What I do is:

- I read the frame of the webcam video using OpenCV, it is a Mat object named `frame`;
- I access the byte array of the `frame` and use it to build a `BufferedImage`;
- The image is shown in a `JPanel` inside its `paint` method.

I am using java version 1.7 and OpenCV 2.4.8 on OS X 10.8.5.

Do you have any suggestion on how I might speed up the whole process?

Regards

Comment: using system.arraycopy seems to give some speedup ( while drawing ), http://answers.opencv.org/question/18304/which-class-can-show-an-image-in-java/  ( look at the last comment )

Comment: Thanks, but I already use System.arraycopy wherever I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,,, it will give u better result

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfByte;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;


public class Robot extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    static BufferedImage bufImagew = null;
    public Robot() {

        JFrame f=new JFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.add(this);
        f.setSize(new Dimension(640,500));

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        VideoCapture camera = new VideoCapture(0);
        // 1 for next camera
        int i = 0;
        try {

            Mat frame = new Mat();
            while (true) {
                    camera.read(frame);
                    Mat image_tmp = frame;

                    MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
                    BufferedImage bufImage = null;

                    if(image_tmp!=null)
                    Highgui.imencode(".jpg", image_tmp, matOfByte); 


                    byte[] byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
                    try {

                        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
                        bufImage = ImageIO.read(in);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    bufImagew=bufImage;
                    this.repaint();
                    if(i==5)
                        i=0;
                } 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        DetectFaceDemo d=new DetectFaceDemo();
        try {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(bufImagew,0,0,null);

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Robot gs = new Robot();
        Thread th = new Thread(gs);
        th.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Since I am using the OpenCV porting to Java made by the Willow Garage, unfortunately I cannot use your code. I will modify my question to make this clear.

Comment: I had done the code as per your need please look through this... i had edited the code... @AntonioSesto

Comment: Thank you, very kind of you. I was finally able to speed up the access: I did not encode the Mat object as a jpg image, but built a BufferedImage using the raw data in Mat (using code found somewhere, possibly here on StackOverflow).